# Book review pirkei avot

Tags: mishna, pirke-avot-ethicsof, artscroll

Does anyone know anything about the artscroll Yad Avraham Pirkei Avot? Please feel free to write a few comments!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What should I use for Mishna study?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/101242/what-should-i-use-for-mishna-study)

Answer (score 1):

Like the entire [Yad Avraham series](https://www.artscroll.com/Categories/YAM.html), it is an extremely detailed commentary, see picture below (apologies for the quality but I have the small edition only). Great for in-depth study or reference but not for everyone.

**See my detailed review [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/101244/11501).**

You might want to consider the more user-friendly [Schottenstein elucidated edition](https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781422623220.html) unless the very detailed notes are what you are looking for.

[image]